# How to combine n confusion matrices

Tags: machine-learning, classification, confusion-matrix

Suppose you have $n$ confusion matrices, each from a different independent classification on a dataset. Suppose each classification is ran on a proper subset of the dataset, and usually these subsets are composed by different elements for each one of the classifications.

E.g.

```
            classification1    classification2    classification3
element1                  1                  1                  1
element2                  1                                     1
element3                                     3                  2
element4                  2                  3
```

How can I summarize the confusion matrices obtained from each classification into an overall one? Is it possible in this case?

Thanks